# Using wildcards in ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible, wildcard

I'm running a script remotely on an ansible client which creates a filename HOSTNAME.html.
I plan to run this on numerous clients in one go, so I need to be able to copy all the files *.html from all the clients.
I'm new to this so have a little playbook.

```
---
- hosts: tariq-test
  tasks:

  - name: run script

    script: /usr/bin/cfg2html-linux

  - name: fetch file

    fetch:
      src: /root/*.html
      dest: /tmp/
      flat: yes
```

And get this:

```
[root@ansible playbooks]# ansible-playbook scp.yml

PLAY [tariq-test] *******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [tariq-test]

TASK [run script] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [tariq-test]

TASK [fetch file] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [tariq-test]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "file not found: /root/*.html"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/playbooks/scp.retry

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
tariq-test                 : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not tested)

Option 1:
If the filename is hostname.html and there is only one file

```
    fetch:
      src: "/root/{{ansible_hostname}}.html"
      dest: /tmp/
      flat: yes
```

Option 2:
Find the files with *.html pattern and then use fetch within loop.

```
- name: Find files
   find:
    path: "{{folder}}"
    pattern: "*.html"
   register: html_files


 - name: Fetch files
   fetch:
      src: "{{item.path}}"
      dest: /tmp/
      flat: yes
   with_items: "{{html_files.files}}"
```

Comment: Hi Smiles
It did and it didn't. Anyway, i'm trying option 2, and the first part, the file the script is generating is being put in /root. What do I put in the double brackets because when I use

name: Find files find: path: "{{root}}" pattern: "*.html" register: html_files

Comment: I get:

TASK [Find files] *********************************************************************************************************** fatal: [DEVGISDB02.GRPDOM.vwuk.corp]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'root' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/run_cfg2html_2.yml': line 9, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n - name: Find files\n ^ here\n"} to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/playbooks/run_cfg2html_2.retry

Comment: Use path: /root